# Error 404: The links on my website don't work, only index (using Codeigniter & .htaccess)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I am hosting my website http://tstspanama.com/ on a Apache server. It was created with the PHP framework Codeigniter. I can only see the home page but nothing else, the links don't work.

If I want to go to `http://tstspanama.com/servicios`, I get:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL `/servicios` was not found on this server

Does anyone have an idea of how ti fix this? I attach all important code.

**On application config (/var/www/tsts/application/config/config.php)**

```
$config['base_url']     = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost' ? 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/' : 'http://www.tstspanama.com/';

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

**On my .htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /tsts/
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|css|js|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value default_charset utf-8
</ifModule>

php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
```

**On /etc/apache2/sites-available/www.tstspanama.com**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.tstspanama.com
    ServerAlias tstspanama.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/tsts
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/tsts>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error,
    # crit, alert, emerg.
    LogLevel error
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: In the future, never post images in place of error messages or code.  This website's search engine only indexes text.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `RewriteBase`, url consider with it, so remove it or use `/`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|css|js|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value default_charset utf-8
</ifModule>

php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
```

Comment: I actually have is as `RewriteBase /tsts/` . Why should I change it? I dont understand very well how this works

Comment: If your **.htaccess** exist with same directory of index.php, it doesn't required. `RewriteBase` add prefix to your path. In the other words, when try to load **http://tstspanama.com/servicios** and you have  `RewriteBase /tsts/`, apache try to load index.php from current directory + `/tsts/` folder. Are you try it?